# How to get file from input on some Android Devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a website with an input type file:

```
<input type="file" id="inputFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

I want to get the file when the user selects one. It works fine when I register an event on change. Here is the code I use:

```
<input type="file" id="inputFile" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
<br><br>

<img id="image" />

var _URL = URL || webkitURL;

var input = document.getElementById("inputFile");
var image = document.getElementById("image");

input.onchange = function() {
    var files = input.files;
    var myFile = files[0];

    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(myFile);

}
```

It works on most mobile devices but on low Android versions like 2.3 I cannot use URL.createObjectURL(myFile) or webkitURL.createObjectURL(myFile).

I created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/confile/y5yru/).

**Is there another way to get the selected file image on Android devices with low version?**

Comment: im not 100% sure but i think it would be much better (well, more compatible with all img types) if you converted with canvas and then extracted.  check this link  http://kristerkari.github.io/adventures-in-webkit-land/blog/2013/03/08/dealing-with-svg-images-in-mobile-browsers/

Comment: @user2515563 coule post an example please?

Comment: there has to be an older equivalent to       URL.createObjectURL(myFile) or webkitURL.createObjectURL(myFile)       i just cant seem to find it ATM, ill keep looking